# How to check if toggle buttons are on and do an action if they are but not all at the same time?

Tags: android, togglebutton

I'm trying to create a very basic app which plays a sound for each toggle button that is toggled when I press a play button but I don't want them to play the sounds at the same time. I want all sounds to be played with a 1 second interval. The play method I created so far doesn't seem to work because I always only hear 1 sound. Here is my play method :

```
    public void play() {
        final Handler hand = new Handler();
        hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (button1.isChecked()) {
                    sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }, 0);
        hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (button2.isChecked()) {
                        sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                    }
                }
                }, 1000);
        hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (button3.isChecked()) {
                        sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                    }
                }
                }, 2000);
        hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (button4.isChecked()) {
                        sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                    }
                }
                }, 3000);
        }
```

I don't really understand why this isn't working properly. Also, is there another easier way to achieve the same goal ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that each instance of a Handler is only associated to a single thread.
You cannot use one Handler like that for up to 4 different Runnables.
You are essentially always overriding the previous set Runnable and therefore can only hear the sound of the last set Runnable.

EDIT (again):

I do not have any Java IDE or even Android Studio currently installed on this device, so the following code is just an idea and is not tested, but I guess it might work.

```
public void play() {

    List<int> soundIDs = new List<int>();

    if (button1.isChecked()) {
        soundIDs.add(snareID);      //you probably might want to set these IDs different, but I assume snareID for example stands for one of the IDs of one of your sound files
    }
    if (button2.isChecked()) {
        soundIDs.add(snareID);
    }
    if (button3.isChecked()) {
        soundIDs.add(snareID);
    }
    if (button4.isChecked()) {
        soundIDs.add(snareID);
    }


    final Handler hand = new Handler();
    hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(soundIDs.size() > 0) {
                sp.play(soundIDs.get(0), 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                soundIDs.remove(0);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

As I've said, I have not tested it and others might have a better solution, but I hope it might work.
The time difference between the sounds is (as in your code) 1000 between each start of the sound. But do keep in mind, that this does not necessarily mean that you have a delay of 1000 between the end of one sound and the start of the next sound.

Comment: So how can I solve this issue? is there another way to achieve my goal? Would it work with a timer?

Comment: Currently in your source code you were always using "snareID" as a parameter. I don't know if this was really your intention. But other than that, I've added an idea of a source code to my answer.

Comment: Yes the idea is that I have 1 sound only (a snare sound) that I want to hear for each toggle button toggled. I will try out your idea of source code and will feedback thanks for the help !

Comment: So I tried it out but it seems that the method next() on this line : "sp.play(soundIDs.next(), 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);" cannot be resolved. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Yes the code is now compilable but it still doens't work unfortunately... I really don't understand what's wrong, now i either only hear once the sound sometimes twice or I press play and i don't hear anything. It's super random and inconsistent. I didn't think that creating an app as simple as playing a sound for each toggle button checked would be so difficult. I even tried doing it by making an array of buttons and checking every button in a "for" condition but it's still the same. Thanks for your time anyway mate.